# OAuth issue in importing google contacts

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

Good Morning - I am using the following YouTube tutorial [Tutoriel PHP - Importer des contacts Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysNVe0TaVFs) to try and import Google contacts.

When I click on the link to import Google contacts, instead of asking for permission and getting the contacts and displaying them on screen, I get the following errors:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Google_Client::authenticate(), called
>   in /var/www/html/restaurant_test/index.php on line 34 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php
>   on line 124
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: code in
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php
>   on line 127
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid code' in
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/lib/google-api-client/Auth/OAuth2.php:88
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php(127):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate(NULL, false) #1
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/index.php(34):
>   Google_Client->authenticate() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/restaurant_test/lib/google-api-client/Auth/OAuth2.php on
>   line 88

Please tell me what to do in order to fix the errors. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"/>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Google Contacts API</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>
<?php
require_once 'lib/google-api-client/autoload.php';
require 'lib/google-api-client/Config.php';
require 'lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php';

$client_id = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.bbbbbb.cccccccccccc.com';
$client_secret = 'oUe3fsfds4gfg23ha93kmKFkfgKZ';
$redirect_uri = 'http://ccccccccccccccccccc.com/rddddddddddd/index.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('contact');
$client -> setClientid($client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');
$client -> setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . $redirect_uri);
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Import Google Contacts</a>';
}else{
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
        $token->access_token;
        $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&access_token=" . $token->access_token);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $contacts_json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $contacts = json_decode($contacts_json, true);
        $return = array();
        foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact){
            $return[] = array(
            'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => isset($contact['gd$email'][0]['address']) ? $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'] : false,
            'phone' => isset($contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']) ? $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'] :false,
            );
        }
        var_dump($return);
    }       
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This  is the function "authenticate" in OAuth2.php in lib/google-api-client/Auth

public function authenticate($code, $crossClient = false) 
{ 
$this->authenticated = true; 
return $this->getAuth()->authenticate($code, $crossClient); 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to pass the `code` to the `authenticate` method. Here's the documentation and implementation of the `authenticate` method in [`Google_Client.php`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php):

```
/**
 * Attempt to exchange a code for an valid authentication token.
 * If $crossClient is set to true, the request body will not include
 * the request_uri argument
 * Helper wrapped around the OAuth 2.0 implementation.
 *
 * @param $code string code from accounts.google.com
 * @param $crossClient boolean, whether this is a cross-client authentication
 * @return string token
 */
public function authenticate($code, $crossClient = false)
{
  $this->authenticated = true;
  return $this->getAuth()->authenticate($code, $crossClient);
}
```

So changing your code as below will most likely resolve the issue:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // <-- Add code parameter here
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . $redirect_uri);
}
```

Comment: [Roby Cornelissen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) - ur right - it solved those errors thanks a lot

Comment: [Robby Cornelissen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) - however, my display is ugly and can only display 50 instead of all